# How to add spring data opensearch to java maven project

Tags: java, maven, opensearch

I want to add this library https://github.com/opensearch-project/spring-data-opensearch to my project

I added dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.opensearch.client</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-opensearch</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

And add repo:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>opensearch-libs-snapshot</id>
        <name>AWS Snapshot Repository</name>
        <url>https://aws.oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

I see this error:

```
Failure to find org.opensearch.client:spring-data-opensearch:jar:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT in https://aws.oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of opensearch-libs-snapshot has elapsed or updates are forced
```

Comment: What makes you think that there is a 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT version? Looking at the project there is a 0.1.0 version.

Comment: As per [this issue on their tracker](https://github.com/opensearch-project/spring-data-opensearch/issues/61), they have not published the library anywhere yet. So the readme is just misleading crap. You can build from source or wait

Comment: Building from source seemed to be the only option at the moment...

Comment: Thanks a lot for answers. Can you please say how to build it add to my java maven app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`spring-data-opensearch` 1.0.0 is [released](https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/org.opensearch.client/spring-data-opensearch/1.0.0).

Quoting from the [README](https://github.com/opensearch-project/spring-data-opensearch#opensearch-2x--1x-client-libraries)

> At the moment, Spring Data OpenSearch provides the possibility to use
> the RestHighLevelCLient to connect to OpenSearch clusters.
>
> ```
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>org.opensearch.client</groupId>
>   <artifactId>spring-data-opensearch</artifactId>
>   <version>1.0.0</version>
> </dependency>
> ```
>
> To use Spring Boot 3.x auto configuration support:
>
> ```
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>org.opensearch.client</groupId>
>   <artifactId>spring-data-opensearch-starter</artifactId>
>   <version>1.0.0</version>
> </dependency>
> ```
>
> To use Spring Boot 3.x auto configuration support for testing:
>
> ```
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>org.opensearch.client</groupId>
>   <artifactId>spring-data-opensearch-test-autoconfigure</artifactId>
>   <version>1.0.0</version>
>   <scope>test</scope>
> </dependency>
> ```